# How to fix Windows Form to only loads full disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I go to run my program, the entire windows form is disabled. There are only four things that the user should be able to do when the screen first loads, type a patient id, click the get patient button, click the add button or the exit button. I have the other boxes set to read only. Is there a property I can change to fix this?

I have tried some code to make sure the parts I need load but this did not work.

```
private void frmPatientMaintenance_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtPatientID.Enabled = true;
            btnGet.Enabled = true;
            btnAddPatient.Enabled = true;
            btnExit.Enabled = true;
        }
```

When the form loads, those four items should be working but the entire form is disabled. I cannot interact with any part of the code other than the X to close out the program. I attached a picture of what the form looks like when I run the program.[image: You can see everything is disabled.]

Comment: Most likely the form itself is disabled. Make it enable as default then use a panel to contain everything except the four controls you want to enable. finally, disabled that panel as default.

Comment: thank you! it was and i did not even think to look at that.

Comment: You could also add the Controls you want enbled to a collection and disable the others. Something like: `List<Control> enabledCtrl = new List<Control>() { txtPatientID, btnGet, btnAddPatient, btnExit }; this.Controls.OfType<Control>().Except(enabledCtrl).ToList().ForEach(ctl => ctl.Enabled = false);`. In `Form.Load()` or `Form.Shown()`. So you don't need to modify your current layout/add new controls.